# Why did my poached egg sink?

Tags: eggs

I tried boiling some water and dropping an egg in, as said in a guide I was watching. But my issue is it immediately sank to the bottom instead? How can I keep the eggs floating at the surface the whole time?

Thanks!

Comment: Did you put enough salt in the water?

Comment: Egg itself may be another factor too.

Comment: THi Dr Bracket, and welcome. To clarify, did you drop in a raw egg, intending to poach it, or did you drop an already poached egg again into water? I suspect it is the first, but the first sentence literally states the second. There is a small grey "edit" button under your post, you can use it to clarify the situation directly into the text.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I cooked thousands of poached eggs during my culinary career, and have never seen one float. And it really does not need to anyway. What is the point? If you want to keep all the whites together, try adding a tsp of so of vinegar and using the freshest eggs you can buy. To keep them from sticking to the bottom of the pas, I use a rubber spatula and lift them off the bottom after a minute of cooking. As with all egg cooking, keep the temperature low. For poached eggs this means just a few tiny bubbles in the water.

Comment: You can cheat by using those silicon poaching cups too. I was pleasantly surprised at how well they worked when I first got mine. I always had trouble getting the poached egg out of the pot without breaking the whites.